# How can I compare photos and PDFs submitted for an online math test to detect for plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism, exams, cheating, tools

I have a group of 1000 students giving an online math test, and 10 teachers (each one evaluating 100 students). Some of the students sent photos and others sent PDF files for their submissions. I already found 2 students that sent the same document (yes, exactly the same), so now I want to compare all documents.

Does there exist any way to compare all the documents to find similar documents?

Comment: Such software exists but I don't think it is free. Ask the institution you work for if they have a subscription. In any case, it would help to require the students to submit a file-format that is easy to process, such as pdf-files and not photos.

Comment: Finding identical files in a directory is simple. Five minutes with python or a similar script language.

Comment: What is the content of those "evaluations"? Multiple choice?  Then you cannot prove anything from identical answers. Written text? Do you have a system to OCR a thousand documents?

Comment: Are these student evaluations of the course or are they something else, such as examinations? It is unclear.

Comment: The evaluation is a "typical" mathematical test, but on-line. The first part consist of alternatives. And in the last question the students must to submit its calculus. The ideia is to compare documents (pdf and images) and detect evident plagiarism only.

@Karl do you have a concrete ideia? I have a good pc and also a linux server in the math departament to run this kind of stuffs. I'm good programming too. Btw, the only word "OCR" is very usefull to me, now I can search on google how I can compare documents.

Comment: Looking for identical images will catch one or two, but try running a google search with a fairly unique phrase from any one of your questions, all inside of quotes, and then the word “Chegg”. What you find may encourage you to check for more than just identical PDFs.

Comment: First thing you should have specified is that all students submit using pdf. images not accepted.